# How can I install pygame without admin permission

Tags: pygame

So I'm coding on my school computer however pip is not installed and neither is pygame. How can I install pygame?

I've tried downloading source code but I don't know how to work that... I can't open any Tar.gz files either. Those are the files on the Pygame Website

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is unpacking the .tar.gz file at home on a computer and copy the pygame folder to a USB. Bring the USB to school and copy the pygame folder to the `site-packages` folder in your python directory.

`site-packages` is the target directory of manually built Python packages. When you build and install Python packages from source (using distutils, probably by executing `python setup.py install`), you will find the installed modules in `site-packages` by default.
For example, if you say `import random` in your code, the module random is actually a python file located in `site-packages`.

The standard location for `site-packages` in Windows is `<python_directory>/Lib/site-packages`

Once you copied your code into `site-packages`, you should be able to import it as you would import `random` or `tkinter` for example, just the normal `import pygame` or `from pygame import <whatever_you_want>`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally pip should be included for Python 2 >= 2.7.9 or Python 3 >= 3.4, if you don't have pip that means you have an older python version. The best solution would be to upgrade it, but I don't have root privileges, so you need to install pip. Here are the docs about it: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/ .

If you have python 3.4+ and pip was removed instead, a simple solution (taken from that link) is to do:

```bash
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

But otherwise, there is something called "[get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)". Latest version is for python 3.7+, but you can get the file for also older versions, like 3.3: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.3/get-pip.py

Here I assume you have python3.3, if you have a different version, change the link accordingly. Run

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.3/get-pip.py | python
```

Now hopefully you have successfully installed pip. You just have to install pygame. Current versions no longer support python 3.3 and below, but pip should find the latest working version. Run
(you may need to restart shell)

```
pip install pygame
```

OR

```
python -m install pip
```

If this fails (for example I'm wrong about pip being able to find a last-supported version), you should try to install the exact version of pygame. It seems like `pygame==2.0.3` is the newest version that still supports python 2.7.

After choosing the pygame version (I used `2.0.3`, change the value to what you want), run

```
pip install pygame==2.0.3
```

OR

```
python -m install pip==2.0.3
```